# How to solve in `basename': no implicit conversion of Array into String

Tags: ruby

I would like to get a filename from ViddlRb without extension.
If i'm running the get_names method with a Youtube URL i'm getting back a array. I'm doing that:

```
    file = ViddlRb.get_names(url)
    file.first
    file.to_s
    puts file
    filename = File.basename(file, '.*')
```

But if i'm running it i'm getting:

> in `basename': no implicit conversion of Array into String

Maybe anyone knows why it breaks? I thought a file.to_s does that job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `file.to_s`, it's returning you the result of the string conversion, but it's *not* modifying your `file` variable. Same with your call to `.first`. Consider this example:

```
file = ["filename.txt"]
file.first
file.to_s
=> "[\"filename.txt\"]"
puts file
=> ["filename.txt"]
```

The easiest way to solve it would be to call `first` and `to_s` within the basename argument. So:

```
filename = File.basename(file.first.to_s, '.*')
```

You could alternately make another variable with it before passing it in.